# Isn't /boot a separate mount?

Tags: linux, mount, partition, grub2, kubuntu

My understanding is that `/boot` is being accessed by lower level tools (e.g. grub) during system startup and so it is formatted specially in a simpler format than the rest of the disk.
But when I do:

```
~$ df  
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sdb1      230693004 4764776 214186584   3% /  
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
udev             3008452       4   3008448   1% /dev  
tmpfs             611080    1220    609860   1% /run  
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock  
none             3055384     368   3055016   1% /run/shm  
none              102400      20    102380   1% /run/user  
/dev/sdb5      368970628 1623180 348581216   1% /home
```

I don't see `/boot` mounted in Kubuntu. Shouldn't it be in this list as a separate mount?
I am using the latest Kubuntu

Comment: That used to be necessary for grub1 some time ago. grub2 understands all sorts of file systems, and LVM and RAID nowadays.

Comment: Even if you had a boot partition, it doesn't have to be mounted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separate `/boot` partition used to be needed (the BIOS in older computers couldn't boot except from the start of the hard drive, and GRUB 1 couldn't boot from some filesystems).

Nowadays you don't really need to have a separate `/boot` partition, except in some specific scenarios (e.g. encrypted root partition). Also, it's used for EFI, as noted in a comment.

Even if you do have one, it doesn't necessarily have to be mounted except when running system updates/upgrades that involve installing new kernels.

Comment: Most newer desktop systems come with UEFI and UEFI mandates an ESP (EFI System Partition) to boot off a disk. I have mine mounted at `/boot/efi` for precisely the reason you mentioned, kernel and initramfs upgrades. So I'd argue that a separate boot partition is more common today than it was the last years.

Comment: None of my computers have EFI, thus I forgot about it. Thanks for noting!

Comment: @Renan:I thought that the bootloader is located always at the start of the boot device.All the tutorials/sources I read same the same thing about this

Comment: The boot loader is located at the start of the boot device, and it eventually will need to load other code (the boot sector is quite small), at least to load the kernel. Some older BIOSes used to have problems with this, thus it was needed for `/boot`  to be the first partition in the drive.

Comment: I think you need /boot for systems that have LVM, since the BIOS isn't able to mount LVM. Is that not the case?

Comment: @slm That BIOS can't boot LVM is corrent, but a bit misleading.  All it does is reading the first sector of the disk and transferring control to it. Then it's up to whatever code fits into this sector to help boot up the system. Which is often reading the partition table and transferring control to a more sophisticated program with less space contraints.

Comment: @Marco - thanks for clarifying. So perhaps the real situation was that grub-legacy as a boot loader wasn't able to boot LVM, so it need to boot the Linux kernel which could, hence the rational for having `/boot` and `/` being separate in the past. Am I framing it right?

Comment: @Marco - hah I just noticed Stephane's comment on the actual Q. Missed that. So now the pictures complete.